# Save line in file to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
file = input('Name: ')

with open(file) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        for name in infile:
            name
            print(name[line])
```

So if a user were to pass a file of vertical list of sentences, how would I save each sentence to its own list?

Sample input:

```
'hi'
'hello'
'cat'
'dog'
```

Output:

```
['hi']
['hello']
and so on...
```

Comment: Please show sample input and expected output

Comment: Edited. Sorry for the vagueness, I was in a hurry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> [line.split() for line in open('File.txt')]
[['hi'], ['hello'], ['cat'], ['dog']]
```

Or, if we want to be more careful about making sure that the file is closed:

```
>>> with open('File.txt') as f:
...    [line.split() for line in f]
... 
[['hi'], ['hello'], ['cat'], ['dog']]
```

Comment: Leaving an open file handler?

Answer (score 3):

```
sentence_lists = []
with open('file') as f:
    for s in f:
        sentence_lists.append([s.strip()])
```

---

simplified as per `idjaw`:

```
with open('file') as f:
    sentence_list = [[s.strip()] for s in f]
```

Comment: You could further simplify by using a comprehension and inside your context manager just do `sentence_list = [[s.strip()] for s in f]`

Comment: what `.strip()` does?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
with open(file) as infile:
    for line in infile.readlines():
        print [line] 
        # list of all the lines in the file as list
```

If the content of file is as:

```
hi
hello
cat
dog
```

It will `print`:

```
['hi']
['hello']
['cat']
['dog']
```

Comment: I would like each line to be put within its own list. As stated in the question.